# Dropdown List from (Bottle) SqLite

Tags: sqlite, drop-down-menu, bottle

I'm tring to do my first web app using python 3.4 and Bottle.

I'm tring do create a dropdown list using data from one table colled "Documenti" (using sqlite)
The table used has only two columns: ID_D (id) and Documents (name of document).
My need is that when a value is choosed, and the botton "search" cliked, Bottle opens a new page, using the ID_D value from the first table and printing info from a second table (colled "Master") thet has also a column colled ID_D.

I'm tring to do this using these codes:

first page with dropdwon list (using first table)

```
@route('/doc')
def Document():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    result = c.execute("SELECT ID_D FROM documenti;").fetchall()
    c.close()
    output = template('doc', rows=result)
    return output
```

Second page, opened using the ID_D from the previous page to print info from the second table

```
@route('/docx', method='GET')
def docx():
    if request.GET.get('search','').strip():
        id = request.GET.get('docx', '').strip()
        conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM master WHERE ID_D LIKE ?;" (id))
        result = c.fetchall()
        c.close()
        output = template('doc3', rows=result)
        return output
```

Here there is my html code used...

in the page with the dropdown list:

```
<form action="/docx" method="GET">
<select name="docx"><option selected="selected" value="">Seleziona</option>
%for row in rows:
    <option value="{{row}}">{{row}}</option>
%end
</select>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search">
```

In the second page (where i wont to see info from the second table using as filter ID_D:

```
<table border="1">
%for row in rows:
  <tr>
  %for col in row:
    <td>{{col}}</td>
  %end
  </tr>
%end
</table>
```

My codes doesn't work...the second page is blank...

Thanks to all for your help!
Mauro

EDIT:
for everyone...this is my working code:

```
@route('/docx', method='GET')
def docx():
    id = request.GET.get('docx', '').strip()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    result = c.execute("SELECT * FROM master WHERE ID_D LIKE (?)", (id,)).fetchall()
    c.close()
    output = template('doc3', rows=result)
    return output
```

Thanks to all guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `if request.GET.get('search','').strip():` is evaluating to `False` and your view is thus returning `None`, which is the default behavior in Python. This makes sense as a `submit` button does not include itself in the query string. I would try this:

```
@route('/docx', method='GET')
def docx():
    id = request.GET.get('docx', '').strip()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM master WHERE ID_D LIKE ?;" (id))
    result = c.fetchall()
    c.close()
    output = template('doc3', rows=result)
    return output
```

If it still doesn't work, I would try right-clicking on the page (when opened in a browser) and selecting `View Source` and you should see a blank page, if you see something like this:

```
<table border="1">
</table>
```

then the SQL query is wrong.

Comment: Tnx iLoveTux...but  now i have another error... when i clinck on the submit botton i have this messages:  " TypeError("'str' object is not callable",) "

Comment: Can you Update your question with the code you changed and the entire traceback?

Comment: I found the solution! Really tnx iLoveTux for your help!

Comment: Any time! You know, if you find that an answer was helpful in solving your problem, it is generally considered good practice to accept and/or upvote it. This really helps motivate people to answer questions as we are all volunteers and the reputation that the above steps provide is our only compensation (kind of like you'd tip the wait-staff).